# Describe free commutative algebra on a set X.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have some difficulties to answer at that question: 
"Describe who is the free commutative $k$-algebra on a set $X$, where $k$ is a commutative ring"

Actually I know the answer: the problem is to give a formal demonstration of the fact that the free commutative $k$-algebra on $X$ is $K[X]$, the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $k$ and commutative indeterminates in $X$.

I find this demonstration on internet, but I don't understand the last two lines, when he says :
"Since $A$ is commutative, $\hat{f}$ factors through $p$, in the sense that there exists a map $f :K⁢[X]→A$ such that $p⁢f = \hat{f}$."
The link where I found the demonstration is that one:

https://planetmath.org/FreeCommutativeAlgebra

Is there someone who can explain me this passage of the demonstration, or can give me another proof of that?

Comment: They wrote $p\tilde{f}=\hat{f}$ where more commonly compositions are written $\tilde{f}p$, since $\tilde{f}:K[X]\to A$ and $p:K\langle X\rangle\to K[X]$. Besides that, they are checking the [definition of free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) in the category of commutative associative algebras (CAA). One has the map of sets $i:X\to F[X]$ sending elements of $X$ to the monomial formed by that single element. Then take an arbitrary CAA called $A$. This is the $B$ in the wikipedia article and a function $f: X\to A$. We need to show the existence of a unique (CAA)map $F[X]\to A$

Comment: such that that map $\tilde{f}:F[X]\to A$, makes the diagram with $i:X\to A$ and $f:X\to F[X]$ commute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I see what are they doing, however I continue to have some problem: why $f^{\tilde}p=f^{^}$? This fact need to be demonstrated, and only then I can use the universal property you state and conclude...

Comment: I think their wording is either too succinct or not very good. It could go like this: First $\hat{f}:F\langle X\rangle \to A$ exists and is unique, from $F\langle X\rangle$ being the free associative algebra (AA). There is a map $\tilde{f}:K[X]\to A$ defined  by $p(X)\mapsto p(f(X))$, where I am abusing notation a writing $f(X)$ for applying $f$ to each element of $X$ and then 'evaluating' the polynomial $p$ on the result. Observe that $\tilde{f}p: K\langle X\rangle\to A$ commutes with the inclusion $X\to K\langle X\rangle$ and $f:X\to A$. Therefore, by the uniqueness of $\hat{f}$ ...

Comment: one must have $\hat{f}=\tilde{f}p$. The 'proof' is rather reducing proving that $K[X]$ is the free CAA to the fact that $K\langle X\rangle$ is the free AA.